# Prop id do not match server, is this serious ? when i publish my website, will it affect that?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

I am using fluent ui in my next-js project, I keep encountering an error
[image]

Whenever I would refresh the page, the styles would break, and the warning shows up.

I managed to resolve it partially, my components styles don't break anymore refreshing the page does no break them anymore. But the warning still shows in the console.

I created a _document.js and that resolved the styles breaking, but the warnig is still there. Should I just ignore the warning ? or is there a way to resolve it ?

this is what I have in the _document.js file //this solution partially from fluent ui's guide, but it is outdated, I am using fluent ui version 8, their solution is for 7 and lower.

```
import * as React from "react";
import Document, { Head, Html, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";
import { Stylesheet, resetIds } from "@fluentui/react";

const stylesheet = Stylesheet.getInstance();

// Now set up the document, and just reset the stylesheet.
export default class MyDocument extends Document {
static async getInitialProps(renderPage) {
resetIds();

const page = await Document.getInitialProps(renderPage);

return {
  ...page,
  styleTags: stylesheet.getRules(true),
  serializedStylesheet: stylesheet.serialize(),
};
}

  render() {
  return (
  <Html>
    <Head>
      <style
        type="text/css"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.props.styleTags }}
      />         

      <script
        type="text/javascript"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: `
        window.FabricConfig = window.FabricConfig || {};
        window.FabricConfig.serializedStylesheet = ${this.props.serializedStylesheet};
      `,
        }}
      />
    </Head>
    <body>
      <Main />
      <NextScript />
    </body>
  </Html>
);
```

}
}